# How do I export an Excel data sheet to a .txt file as Delimiter colon?

Tags: excel, database, delimiter

I have a .txt file that was given to me (exported from a database) that includes columns and rows. I was told some of data was in the wrong column. I just needed to move it to the next column over. I opened the .txt file in Excel using the Data "From Text/CSV" option and made my changes. Once I was finished, I saved my file as a .txt file like it was given to me, however it's not in the same format. My .txt export kept the column and rows whereas the original file given to me had the information had the values separated with "|" characters. Do you know how I can get the data in the "|" format so I can send it back to them? See my screenshots for reference.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR5bG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have opened the file in Excel and made your changes, you can use the steps in below [link here](https://www.automateexcel.com/how-to/convert-save-as-pipe-delimited/) to change the delimiter to "|" or anything else you would like...

Comment: Thank you @Redox ! Do you know how I could get the quotation marks around the values? Is there a way I can do that in Notepad++? I also notice the .txt file needs to be in a Unix (LF)  UTF-8 format.